# Finding a counter example : $[0,1] \times X\to K(X)$ is not continuous, where $X$ is finite set and $K(X)$ is the set of closed set of $X$.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, continuity

Let $X$ be a compact metric space and K(X) the set of closed subsets of X. That is, $(K(X),d_H)$ is also a compact metric space, where $d_H$ is the Hausdorff metric. If X is a finite set, then $[0,1]\times X\to K(X)$ is not continuous.

I would like to find an example of this problem. Is this correct?

> Let $\mathcal C$ be a circular arc in the plane $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the Euclidean metric. $$B_r:\mathcal{C \to K(C)}$$ Then $B_r$ is discontinuous with respect to $x$ for some $r$. 
>  [image]

Comment: How do you define the map $[0,1] \times X \to K(X)$?

Comment: Let $B:[0,1]\times X\to K(X)$. $B_r(x)\in K(X)$ where $r\in [0,1]$ for example, $B_0(x)=\{x\}, B_1(x)=X$. $B_r(x)$ is closed ball. (
I do not speak English well. I hope you understand.)

Comment: Let me make sure I understand. $B$ takes a number in $[0,1]$ and a point $x$, and gives back the closed ball of radius that number centered at $x$?

Comment: yes, yes right.

Comment: The image is not about the finite case, though

Comment: @blowup you should state all the details on the map $[0,1]\times X \to K(X)$ in your question: it is un-understanble as stated

Answer (score 3):

If $X$ is finite, so is $K(X)$ and $[0,1] \times X$ is just a finite union of compact intervals, each of which must be mapped to a single point of $K(X)$ under $f$ if we have a conrinuous map $f : [0,1] \times X \rightarrow K(X)$. This holds as $K(X)$ is finite $T_1$ so totally disconnected, while $[0,1]$ is connected.

You are considering, per the comment, $f(r,x) = B(r,x)$, the (closed, I suppose) ball of $x$ with radius $r$. So for every fixed $x$: $f[[0,1] \times \{x\}]$ should be  constant if $f$ were continuous, but in fact $f(0,x) = \{x\}$ and $f(1,x) = X$ and $X \neq \{x\}$. So for finite but not singleton $X$ the map cannot be continuous.

Comment: thank you. but i don't understand last "$f(0,x)=\{x\}$ and $f(0,1)=X$ and $X\neq \{x\}$" ... I would appreciate it if you could explain it in more detail.

Comment: I meant $f(1, x)$ and I assume the metric is bounded by $1$. Both are in the same $[0,1]\times \{x\}$ but have different images, contrary what continuity would force.

Comment: thank you so much. It is a great help to study. thank you!! :)

Comment: @hyunheelee glad I could help.

Comment: If you okay, I just want to ask you one more question. Can you explain the picture above? please click "enter images".